# weird exception while using support v4 split version 24.2.0

Tags: android, android-support-library

When I use these two module, there is an exception as below:

```
compile ('com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.0')
compile ('com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.2.0')
```

exception:

```
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define    Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs;
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

But when I change the two above to the **BIG** one, exception gone!!!

```
compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0')
```

THis is my original build.gradle, i just what to upgrade support-v4

```
dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
 compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
 compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
 compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Anyone knowns why this happens and how to fix it??? thanks.

Comment: post yoiur `build.gradle`

Comment: sorry, just add it

Comment: what about `24.1.0`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya hi, I think the split version is 24.2.0. As I mentioned above, use the full support-v4 library is ok. exception only happens when I change the "whole" library to splited ones.

Comment: add `dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    incremental true
}` and make sure enable `multiDexEnabled true`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya  Just tried, still not work...